# Read number after specific word

Tags: php

I'm trying to read a number in a link in php. But I'm not sure how to do it.

```
http://example.com/Productdetail.asp?SID=72&ProductID=8640
```

How can I read the number `8640` without reading `72` at the same time.

`ProductID=` `<-` it will always be there.

`SID=X` `<-` this one will be there sometimes and left out on other pages. and the number can change between `1-999`,

Is there a way to say `ProductID= "read the next 4 numbers and save in string"`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can get this output by using `explode()`

```
$link='http://example.com/Productdetail.asp?SID=72&ProductID=8640';

    $links=explode('ProductID=',$link);
    echo $link[1]; //this is your number
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple use

```
echo $_GET['ProductID'];//8640
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_match` as

```
$str = "http://example.com/Productdetail.asp?SID=72&ProductID=8640";
preg_match('/&ProductID=(\d+)?/',$str,$match);
echo $match[1];
```

Or you can simply use `parse_str` as

```
$str = "http://example.com/Productdetail.asp?SID=72&ProductID=8640";
parse_str($str,$res);
echo $res['ProductID'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

1. [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to get the ProductID= 
   's index
2. [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to get the string from ProductID= until the end of the string
3. [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace the ProductID= part

```
    <?php
        $str = "http://example.com/Productdetail.asp?SID=72&ProductID=8640";    
        echo str_replace("ProductID=", "", substr($str, strpos($str, "ProductID=")));
    ?>
```